# Best way to find n-th element list item in html list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic list (`<ul><li></li></ul>`)of items (three columns)

I need to add some margin to the items that appears at the top in the three columns. I just to have only one column and I could do

```
$('ul.dynamic').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').first().addClass('menuMargin');
});
```

but now I have three columns so what's the best way to add this class to first, 9th and 17th list item (8 items in each column) with jQuery/JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the top of each column need extra margin? Can't you just add padding to the `ul`? Are you sure that this wouldn't be better marked up as three lists?

Comment: Hi Eric, the top items need extra margin because the designer says so :) the list is rendered from a dynamic navigation so everything comes in one list/column that I use some other CSS for to split it up in three columns.

Comment: Yes, but `padding` on the container is the same as `margin` on the list items. Are you sure you don't mean border? What does `.menuMargin` do?

Comment: If the list is "dynamic" why are you trying to find the 9th and 17th items specifically? Don't you want a more dynamic solution?

Comment: How are you planning to make the items flow in columns? That's pretty impossible. It's much easier to make them flow in rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ul = $('ul.dynamic');
ul.find("li:first-child, li:nth-child(9), li:nth-child(17)").addClass("menuMargin");
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector) and [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Just add padding to the container:

```
ul { padding-top: 50px; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/dxWG8/)